# How to find out which Camera format in Settings?

Tags: ios, ios11, heif

For iOS 11, in Settings -> Camera -> Formats, user can choose between High Efficiency vs Compatible. How do we know from the SDK which one the user chooses so we can persist image capture in the right format?

Comment: In my opinion this does not matter since you are getting an `UIImage` from the framework which does not represent any kind of format.

Comment: @rckoenes It does matter - I want to persist the UIImage data to HEIC or JPEG depending on what the user has chosen in their Camera format in Settings.

Comment: True if You store the image in your app. But saving to the camera roll only accepts UIImage object. Which are then saved in the users preferred image format.

Comment: @rckoenes Need it to save the image on my own, not camera roll/photo album.